# List values changing where they should remain constant

Tags: python, list, tuples

I was playing around with some code earlier, and I noticed something rather strange, and I haven't been able to explain it.

Below are two functions that are exactly the same except for one thing. The variable `origionalPos` is a list in the first function and a tuple in the second one.

```
def ticking_as_list():
    tick = False
    ticking = False
    originalPos = [0,0]
    pos = [0,0]

    x = 0
    RUNNING = True
    while RUNNING:
        x += 1
        if x % 50 == 0:
            tick = not tick
            ticking = not ticking

        if ticking:
            originalPos = pos
            ticking = False

        pos[0] = originalPos[0] + 10
        pos[1] = originalPos[1] + 10

        if x == 500:
            RUNNING = False
            print(pos)

def ticking_as_tuple():
    tick = False
    ticking = False
    originalPos = (0,0)
    pos = [0,0]

    x = 0
    RUNNING = True
    while RUNNING:
        x += 1
        if x % 50 == 0:
            tick = not tick
            ticking = not ticking

        if ticking:
            originalPos = (pos[0],pos[1])
            ticking = False

        pos[0] = originalPos[0] + 10
        pos[1] = originalPos[1] + 10

        if x == 500:
            RUNNING = False
            print(pos)
```

The functions are set to change the values of `pos` and add 10 to them every time `x` is divisible by 50 and print the result when it equals 500. There are far easier ways to do this I know, but that is not the subject of the question.

When I run either of these functions, I expected to get an output of `[110,110]` from both of them, however; when I actually ran them, the output is as follows:

```
>>> ticking_as_list()
[4520,4520]
>>> ticking_as_tuple()
[110,110]
```

The function with `ticking` as a list is obviously much higher than when it is a tuple. When I look at what is happening as each function executes by printing `pos` while each function executes, it shows that 10 is added to `pos` on every iteration while only after every 50th iteration when it is a tuple as it should.

Why is it that the list always updates even when the value `ticking` is equal to false? As shown in the code:

```
        if x % 50 == 0:
            tick = not tick
            ticking = not ticking

        if ticking:
            originalPos = pos
            ticking = False
```

`ticking` only becomes true when `x` is divisible by 50, and immediately becomes false afterward. Which should make `originalPos` only update when that is true, however; it doesn't. It does work correctly as a tuple value though. Why is this? If I had accidentally changed changed the value anywhere else, an error would be raised in the tuple function because because tuples are static, and if the logic in other parts of the function were off, the tuple function would output the same as the list function.

What is the reason this happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line `originalPos = pos` does not make a new list, it only gives the existing list a new name. To create a new list, you can use an empty [list slice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/explain-pythons-slice-notation).

```
originalPos = pos[:]
```

**Edit:** It looks like an explicit [`copy`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types) method was added in Python 3.3.

```
originalPos = pos.copy()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    if ticking:
        originalPos = pos
        ticking = False
```

The second statement makes the variable `originalPos` reference the *same* list as `pos`, so from there on changing one also changes the other. You probably want to copy over the actual values in the `pos`, so [take a look at this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list-in-python).

In short

```
originalPos = pos[:]
```

should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is here:

```
originalPos = pos
```

You just use a reference, i.e. `originalPos` and `pos` are two names for the same object.

Change it to:

```
originalPos = pos[:]
```

and you get:

```
>>> ticking_as_list()
[110, 110]
```

This is the same result as for the tuple version.